# Displaying Meta Tag Keywords as JSON Data From Database Not Seem To Be Working

Tags: php, json, laravel, meta-tags, laravel-5.8

I'm working with Laravel 5.8 and I wanted to update my page meta keywords as JSON data.

So I created a new column named `prd_meta_keywords` and set its structure to `JSON`.

Now I can successfully insert JSON data into this column like this example:

```
[
    "video product",
    "new product"
]
```

And for retrieving this data on the Blade, I did this:

```
@section('meta')
   <meta name="keywords" content="@if(!empty($product->prd_meta_keywords)) @if(is_array($product->prd_meta_keywords) || is_object($product->prd_meta_keywords)) @foreach(json_decode($product->prd_meta_keywords) as $keyword) {{$keyword}}{{$loop->remaining ? ',' : ''}} @endforeach @endif @endif">
@endsection
```

But as you can see, it does not work and does not show the keywords on page source code:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="  ">
```

However I can properly get result from `@dd(json_decode($product->prd_meta_keywords))`.

So what's going wrong here? How can I retrieve this JSON data as keyword tags properly in the Blade?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Laravel Casting](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) there.

Just `cast` your column in the respective model. So it will auto store data in `JSON` and at the time of retrieving it will auto-cast in PHP array.

```
 protected $casts = [
     'prd_meta_keywords' => 'array',
 ];
```

After retrieving the array you can easily implode in meta,

```
<meta name="keywords" content="{{ ($product->prd_meta_keywords) ? implode(",", $product->prd_meta_keywords) : ''}}">
```

Let me know the results.

Comment: It works dude, but I would like to know what's going wrong in my code as well...

Comment: Can you please share the result of ```@dd(json_decode($product->prd_meta_keywords))```?

Comment: I think the problem is this condition ```@if(is_array($product->prd_meta_keywords) || is_object($product->prd_meta_keywords))``` just remove this condition. Also replace ```@foreach(json_decode($product->prd_meta_keywords) as $keyword)``` with ```@foreach(json_decode($product->prd_meta_keywords, true) as $keyword)```. Let me know the results.

Comment: If I remove that, I get `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: Did you also replaced ```@foreach(json_decode($product->prd_meta_keywords) as $keyword)``` with ```@foreach(json_decode($product->prd_meta_keywords, true) as $keyword)```?

Comment: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240127/discussion-between-vivek-pawar-and-nagidi).